# Importing module from parent folder subfolder to run in scripts subfolder [siblings]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

My project structure looks like this:

```
project/
|--- helper_modules/
    |--- util.py
|--- scripts/
    |--- A.py
```

If I put the script A.py in the project/ folder, it runs and imports successfully using `from helper_modules.util import fn`. But I have a number of scripts and to keep things organised I'd like to have them all in their own subfolder. How can I do this and still import from helper_modules?

I'm in the directory /project/ when I call the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this which gave me a workaround. Apparently [this can't be done by default in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

In each script in the scripts folder, I started with this code:

```
# add to the Python path to import helper functions
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need add this in your script A.py :

```
from ..helper_modules.util import fn
```

and run A.py exiting one level from the project folder, so if you are in project folder do:

```
cd ..
```

Then run A.py using

```
python -m project.scripts.A
```

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory is `/project/`, you should launch the script using:

```
python -m scripts.A
```

And from within `scripts/A.py`, you can do

```
from helper_modules.util import fn
```